# SonarQube Error during SonarScanner execution: SQL Scan Memory Error

Tags: sql, jenkins, sonarqube, cicd, sonarqube-scan

I am using the developer SonarQube version 9.1. I have this one PL/SQL file and I want to do job at Jenkins. Now, I am doing SonarQube and Jenkins for PL/SQL scanning. I already upload the source code at gitlab and do the scanning through Jenkins. It should be able to scan 1 billion codes but when I try to configure into Jenkins, I got this error. Any suggestion or idea related on this issue?

I have already do the scanning but failed because of over memory.

[image]